# Different datetime in azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, datetime, localtime

I'm writing `DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime(),` - gives me the real-time, but in azure, it gives a difference of 2 hours back (maybe from the server location). Is there a way to make them the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, on Azure App Service, the time zone is always UTC, but you can change it.

If you haven't done this already, you need to set WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE variable in Application settings > under App settings, add this setting:

o Key = WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE
o Value = The time zone you want

Save, the above settings and then check.

For the App services that run on Windows, see the Timezone column in the [Default Time Zones article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones) for accepted values. For the App services that run on Linux, set the TZ database name as the time zone value.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/35375/azure-local-time-is-incorrect-for-all-but-web-serv.html

Answer (score 0):

Add environment variable `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`, 1 option is in **application settings**

- If running on linux, use [tz database name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- If running on Windows, use [windows server time zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones)

Example

```
+-------------------+---------------------------+------------------+
|   Variable name   |          Windows          |      Linux       |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------------------+
| WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE | AUS Eastern Standard Time | Australia/Sydney |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: But I don't have variable WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE in application settings...

Comment: @BeginnerInIT You add it yourself